# Execute process and get result on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, process

I've got a piece of code that executes a process and retrieves the result.

```
namespace {
    FILE* really_popen(const char* cmd, const char* mode) {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        return _popen(cmd, mode);
#else
        return popen(cmd, mode);
#endif
    }
    void really_pclose(FILE* pipe) {
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        _pclose(pipe);
#else
        pclose(pipe);
#endif
    }
    std::string ExecuteProcess(std::string cmd) {
        FILE* pipe = really_popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
        if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("Could not invoke command " + cmd);
        char buffer[128];
        std::string result = "";
        while(!feof(pipe)) {
            if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                result += buffer;
        }
        really_pclose(pipe);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works just fine for me on Linux, but on Windows, it has a terrible habit of deadlocking- seems that `fgets` never returns. I've looked into the CRT sources and `fgets` eventually delegates to `ReadFile`, which never returns.

If I invoke the command from the command line, it returns within a second.

How can I read the output on Windows without deadlocking the parent?

Comment: When the parent is deadlocked, has the child actually exited?  Is the parent a console application?

Comment: No and yes. The child seems to be fine if you invoke it separately so I'm certainly not feeling that it's a bug in the child process.

Comment: It should be very easy to use a debugger or some tracing to stderr in both, the parent and the child. So I really do not understand why you bother the whole wide world with this problem.


We have 2015. This is 19 years (or even more) after the availability of C++ Exception Handling and RAII for fallible system calls. So there is no excuse for using C functions like popen/pclose/fgets which do not inform the caller about system error codes. Get current with the previous millennia!

Comment: If the child hasn't exited, then the call to fgets() won't exit.  The most likely cause is that the child has hung because it has no standard input, so try changing the pipe mode to "rw".

Comment: @ExcessPhase: _popen and _fgets both return NULL if an error occurs.  The code properly checks the return value of _popen; it doesn't respond properly if _fgets fails, but if that was the problem the symptoms would be different.

Comment: @Harry Johnston:
NULL stands for which system error?
What about the source of system errors -- there are multiple system calls involved in popen.
See the documentation of CreateProcess/CreatePipe (fork/execvp/pipe) for the range of possible system errors.

Comment: @ExcessPhase: since he isn't *getting* a NULL, the question is moot.

Comment: @ExcessPhase: The problem isn't in the error handling in the parent. The parent never gets an error to handle. And the child is a process which I don't own and don't have the symbols for.

Comment: @Puppy: I did not answer the question. I commented on this code. This code will lead to future problems, when suddenly something does not work at a customer site (or even for a developer) and the customer does not have any clue what caused the problem.

Comment: @ExcessPhase: One of the advantages of a home hobby project: I don't need to give a single shit about such situations. And FTR, your comment implies that I don't know about EH or RAII (despite the fact that I actually used a throw in the function body), which is at best, completely untrue. This particular piece of code is simply a piece that just doesn't matter enough for me to spend time on.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That is a good shout- I had not considered this as a potential error, but the Linux *caller* adds `< /dev/null` to their argument. Adding `< NUL` to the Windows version seems to resolve the problem. Post as answer so I can accept.

Comment: @Puppy can you edit your code with the correct solution? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the child hasn't exited, then the call to fgets() won't exit, so you need to resolve why the child isn't exiting.  The most likely cause in this sort of situation is that the child has hung because it has no standard input.

If that's the problem, you may be able to resolve it by changing the pipe mode to "rw".  You won't typically need to do anything with the extra pipe, it just has to be there.

(As you mention in the comments, the problem can also be resolved by using the command shell redirection to give the child a handle to `NUL` as standard input.)